# How timed loop works?

Tags: go

I am learning golang, and I just came to know about the timed loop. But I don't understand how is it working?

```
for _ = range time.Tick(time.Second * 3) {
    fmt.Println("Ticking every 3 seconds")
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tick](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Tick) returns a `<-chan Time` channel, and in Go looping over channels with `range`, just as you would loop over an array or a map, is a ok. When you loop over a channel the code inside the loop gets executed on every `recieve` from that channel, which in your example would happen every 3 seconds. The loop terminates after that channel is closed.

https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4